# Difference between Emulator and Real Device for Installed applications?

Tags: android, android-emulator

What is the difference for installed application's list in device and emulator. In emulator i can see the installed apps in location of `/data/app`

But, i can't see the installed application on my real device. Where it is stored. I can see the default application from here `/system/app` But i can't see installed application whatever i downloaded and my own application. Anyone guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the emulator, you have root access.

On your phone, you do not have root access (unless you root it). And each application gets its own private folder with its own linux userid, so that one application can not look into the folder of another application. This is but only one aspect of the Android security model. There are many more.

Are you looking for anything in particular in those folders? If so, there are workarounds. For instance, if you're trying to look at your sqlite.db file, one workaround is to have your own application (since it has the permission to do so) programmatically read the database file and reconstitute it on the SD card (every time you want to manually check it).

Comment: How can i get the root access for my device?

Comment: Just google for it: How can I get root access for <device name>. I would post a link, but I'm not sure that's allowed.

Comment: My device name is Samsung Galaxy S2

Comment: What i found? I can't understand. My device name is Samsung galaxy s2

Comment: Did you try googling for the rooting instructions for your device?

Comment: Ya i searched for that. But, i didn't get any answer from there. If you know means tell me the way.

Comment: Really? The first two hits give you the answer. http://www.google.com/search?aq=1&oq=how+to+root+Samsung+Galaxy+S2&gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=how+to+root+samsung+galaxy+s2

Answer (score 1):

In my device (Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, Android 3.1) installed apps are in `/data/data`.

EDIT: If you want to get absolute path of your directory at runtime, you can use this trick:

```
getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().replaceFirst("/file.*$", "");
```

Comment: My Device (Samsung Galaxy S2) I've /data/data directory. But, it shows only empty directory. What can i do?

Comment: You see your directory empty because you cannot enter into it. There are only a few root devices. If all devices would allow root access, Android has a big security flaw ...

Comment: Okay, shall i know if there's any Uri available for installed application's like this - content//sms/inbox